# JQ applying function to dict but print surrounding datas

Tags: jq

I'd like

```
"1": {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "select",
        "label": "country :",
        "choices": {
          "1": {
            "label": "Canada CAN",
            "value": "",
          },
          "2": {
            "label": "United States USA",
            "value": ""
          }
        }
}
```

to produce

```
"1": {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "select",
        "label": "country :",
        "choices": {
          "1": {
            "label": "Canada",
            "value": "CAN",
          },
          "2": {
            "label": "United States",
            "value": "USA"
          }
        }
}
```

By now I have a two-step solution consisting of a sed-like function

```
def do_extract:
if .value | test("^$") then
    (.value = (.label | capture(".* (?<code>...)")).code) | .label = (.label | capture("(?<name>.*) ...$").name)
else
    .
end;
```

and a direct access to the sub-tree `[]."1"."choices"|keys_unsorted as $key|map_values(do_extract)` but I have to manually copy-paste the output in place of the original "choices" dict.

Is there a way to do the function but still print the surrounding datas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to get your desired result, you could do this:

```
.[].choices[] |= (.label | capture("^(?<label>.*?) (?<value>[^ ]+)$"))
```

To do that within your function, I'd change it to this:

```
def do_extract:
  if .value == "" then
    (.label | capture("^(?<label>.*?) (?<value>[^ ]+)$"))
  else
    .
  end;
```

Then use it:

```
.[].choices[] |= do_extract
```